# nginx: redirecting only 'www' subdomain to main domain?

Tags: nginx, subdomain, forwarding

Update: April 20th 2013, Still no solution found, please help

Looking at my nginx config, the only like that could be the culprit is this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
        rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}
```

Literally I need 'www' to be redirected to the main domain.

Could this be done in nginx?

I am a bit confused about this matter and Godaddy support is telling me each time something different.

I have forwarded my www domain to the main domain and it doesn't work.

```
www.domain --> domain.com     Fails
```

However any other subdomain such as test, can be forwarded to the main domain without any trouble.

```
test.domain --> domain.com    Ok
```

Godaddy claims:

> or this you will need to setup a www CNAME that maps to @. On your
>   host, you can setup a coded redirect https://domain.com in an index
>   file or .htacess file.

I don't understand how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first configure your DNS zone as such:

```
@   IN A <IP ADDRESS>
www IN A <IP ADDRESS>
```

Using this configuration, anything like `www.example.com`, and `example.com` will be resolved to `IP ADDRESS` which should be your Web server's IP address.

Then, in your Nginx configuration you put this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  In fact I would like to forward only www.mydomain.com to --> mydomain.com.  I don't wish to forward all subdomains.  You know what I mean?  So you suggest to create an A-record with www to my IP? Or a C-name with www to my IP? I have that nginx setting already the way you have described it.

Comment: @Kave, I've edited my answer.

Comment: many thanks.  But the moment I add this part:  the `https://example.com` doesn't work anymore.  But when I remove it it works again. Why?
`server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}`

Comment: @Kave, check the configuration with `nginx -t` and what's your nginx version?

Comment: It says: `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`  I have nginx version: `nginx version: nginx/1.2.7`

Comment: Ah OK, I understood. Normally you cannot use 2 SSL hosts using the same IP address. However, this should be well supported nowadays. Have you set up your certificates for both SSL hosts? Check out the documentation on how to set up [multiple HTTPS servers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#name_based_https_servers).

Comment: +1 Ahh the certificates were missing for the new `www` entry. :)) Thank you so much. You are a real pro.  I have exchanged 12 emails with GoDaddy support and they had no clue. You are a real pro.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex in this task, by the way.
Try this config, for example.

```
server {
        listen *:80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
        return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. I changed that but the actual problem remains.  I recon the forwarding of a subdomain falls into Godaddy's responsibility and not my nginx, is that right?

Comment: I think so. Maybe you should disable any "forwarding" at Godaddy? Just  create CNAME record (or records) for each name (such "test.domain.com") pointing to main domain.